# HTML,JavaScript, JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following json data . How can i show the 'record' values in a html table by using only javascript and html. This json data is a string.

```js
{
    "document": {
        "record": [
            {
                "a": "36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-1",
                "WForderdate2332532": "2012-06-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                "WFregion2332540": "East",
                "WFrep2332556": "Jones",
                "WFitem2332585": "Pencil",
                "WFunits2332555": "95.00",
                "WFcost2332532": "1.99",
                "WFtotal2332589": "189.05",
                "b": "2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00",
                "c": "2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00",
                "d": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com",
                "e": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"
            },
            {
                "a": "36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-2",
                "WForderdate2332532": "2012-03-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                "WFregion2332540": "Central",
                "WFrep2332556": "Kivell",
                "WFitem2332585": "Binder",
                "WFunits2332555": "50.00",
                "WFcost2332532": "19.99",
                "WFtotal2332589": "999.50",
                "b": "2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00",
                "c": "2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00",
                "d": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com",
                "e": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"
            },
           ]
         }
       }
```

Comment: Please give your question a name describing what it is about. You also need to show us what you have done and what's not working. This is not a free programming service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var myjson = {
  "document": {
    "record": [{
      "a": "36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-1",
      "WForderdate2332532": "2012-06-01T00:00:00+00:00",
      "WFregion2332540": "East",
      "WFrep2332556": "Jones",
      "WFitem2332585": "Pencil",
      "WFunits2332555": "95.00",
      "WFcost2332532": "1.99",
      "WFtotal2332589": "189.05",
      "b": "2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00",
      "c": "2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00",
      "d": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com",
      "e": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"
    }, {
      "a": "36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-2",
      "WForderdate2332532": "2012-03-01T00:00:00+00:00",
      "WFregion2332540": "Central",
      "WFrep2332556": "Kivell",
      "WFitem2332585": "Binder",
      "WFunits2332555": "50.00",
      "WFcost2332532": "19.99",
      "WFtotal2332589": "999.50",
      "b": "2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00",
      "c": "2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00",
      "d": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com",
      "e": "pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"
    }, ]
  }
};
var records = myjson.document.record;
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]
  //console.log(table.tHead.rows[0])
  //console.log(table);

for (var key in records[0]) {
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key))
  table.tHead.rows[0].appendChild(th);
}

for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(i)
  for (var key in records[0]) {
    td = document.createElement("td")
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(records[i][key]))
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need basically three steps:

1. convert the string to actual javascript data
2. find the columns
3. build the output

### 1. convert to javascript data

This is easy... just `data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);`

### 2. find the columns

If you don't know in advance what are the columns you must iterate over all records to find what are their names. Note that it's possible that different record have different "columns".

```
var cols = {};
data.document.record.forEach(function(row){
    row.forEach(function(col){
        cols[col] = 1;
    });
});
```

### 3. build the output

For this there are two common ways; create the HTML string or create the DOM node elements. The following is using the second method:

```
var domtable = document.createElement("table");
document.appendChild(domtable);
data.document.record.forEach(function(row){
    var domrow = document.createElement("tr");
    domtable.appendChild(domrow);
    cols.forEach(function(col){
        var domcell = document.createElement("td");
        domcell.textContent = row[col];
        domrow.appendChild(domrow);
    });
});
```

note that if you want to style your elements using CSS to set the class names the code required is for example `domcell.className = "cell"`.

### 4. ???

...

### 5. profit

:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the 'record' array by :

```
var records = document.record;
```

To iterate over the records, you can do:-

```
for(var index in records) {
   var record = records[index];
   // Now you can access individual values like record.a
   // However your JSON structure seems to be very dynamic so you can also iterate over these keys as well.
   for(var key in record) {
       var valueForKey =  record[key];
       // Now you can set this value to specific HTML elment either via jQuery or simple JavaScript depending on your comfort.

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:800px;overflow: auto">
        <table id="dataTable" border="1">
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        var dataString = '{"document":{"record":[{"a":"36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-1","WForderdate2332532":"2012-06-01T00:00:00+00:00","WFregion2332540":"East","WFrep2332556":"Jones","WFitem2332585":"Pencil","WFunits2332555":"95.00","WFcost2332532":"1.99","WFtotal2332589":"189.05","b":"2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00","c":"2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00","d":"pritamb@greencubeglobal.com","e":"pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"},{"a":"36a0bb3a1653420fac1ffdbf6f1fc495-2","WForderdate2332532":"2012-03-01T00:00:00+00:00","WFregion2332540":"Central","WFrep2332556":"Kivell","WFitem2332585":"Binder","WFunits2332555":"50.00","WFcost2332532":"19.99","WFtotal2332589":"999.50","b":"2014-12-19T05:59:04+00:00","c":"2014-12-19T05:59:05+00:00","d":"pritamb@greencubeglobal.com","e":"pritamb@greencubeglobal.com"}]}}';
        function createTable() {
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(dataString);
            var records = dataObj["document"]["record"];
            var rowString = "";
            var headRow = "<tr>";
            var headObj = records[0];
            for (var key in headObj) {
                headRow += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
            }
            headRow += "</tr>";
            for (var key in records) {
                rowString += '<tr>';
                var obj = records[key];
                var tdString = "";
                for (var key1 in obj) {
                    tdString += "<td>" + obj[key1] + "</td>";
                }
                rowString += tdString;
                rowString += "</tr>";
            }
            rowString = headRow + rowString;
            $("#dataTable").html(rowString);
        }
        createTable();
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```